# Virtualbox doesnt work anymore

Tags: virtualbox

Suddenly, without warning, Virtualbox no longer opens the Windows 10 virtual machine. According to the error message, "Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

No other Virtual Machines that I tried to install open.   The process of correcting the error does not work either, and I do not find a solution. My system is Ubuntu 20.04 installed on a Dell XPS 13 9310, Kernel 5.14.0-1044-oem.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the *exact error message* that you are seeing, not a paraphrase of it.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` ? If that doesn't fix it then you need to either boot an older kernel (from the 5.13.x line) or update VirtualBox to the latest version

Comment: Running sbin/vboxconfig, i get the error message: See the documenatation for your Linux distribution..
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
vboxdrv.sh: Failed to enroll secure boot key..
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.

Comment: I have the latest version of Virtualbox. Regarding a previous kernel, I don't know how to do it, but also the current kernel has been in use for a long time and then everything worked fine.

Comment: dmesg command give a very long answer i don't understand

Comment: Is Secure Boot enabled on your system? If it is, and you did not go through the MOK process, virtualbox will not run. The simplest fix is to turn off Secure Boot.

Comment: Well, thanks for the advice, but I don't know how to reverse the process with Secure Boot on my computer, Dell XPS 13. I appreciate any more detailed explanation.  Josef